# Пельмени из мяса филе индейки - что не так в этом словосочетании?

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Допустимо ли так сформулировать? Или филе - это и так мясо, поэтому "мясо" лишнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Филе — (фр. filet). Термин, которым обычно обозначают лучшую, самую нежную и вкусную и самую дорогую часть мяса домашних животных, птицы, дичи и рыбы. У свинины, телятины и говядины филе называют либо вырезку, либо часть между вырезкой и покромкой (филе в узком поварском смысле). Источник: Кулинарный словарь.
Если опираться на устойчивые словосочетания «филейная (отборная) часть туши», «филейное мясо», где слово «филе» русифицировано до «филейный», то получаем вполне удобоваримое:
*Пельмени из филейного мяса индейки.*
Слово «филе» многозначно. Для «филе» в значении «вырезка», т.е. часть, отрезанная от целой туши, наиболее близким по звучанию и смыслу видится слово «филиал» - отделение (компании), что тоже часть, отсеченная от целого.

Answer (score 3):

Словосочетание "филе индейки" в данном случае вполне однозначно указывает на то, что речь идет именно о мясе птицы, поэтому слово "мясо" здесь можно опустить:

> **Пельмени из филе индейки.**

Другое дело, что по каким-либо юридическим причинам слово "мясо" может быть обязательным в названии. В таком случае словосочетание "филе индейки" можно взять в скобки или даже кавычки:

> **Пельмени из мяса (филе индейки).**
> **Пельмени из мяса "филе индейки".**

Либо так:

> **Пельмени из мясного филе (филе индейки).**

В последнем примере слово "филе" в скобках является факультативным.

Comment: Почему филе не обязательно мясо? И разве мясо рыбы это не мясо? Здесь нужно чуть аккуратнее с различными значениями слова "мясо" и со словоупотреблением. Для примера, "лососина" в любом толковом словаре — мясо лосося.

Comment: Обычно на бытовом уровне понятия "рыба" и "мясо" все-таки противопоставляются. В каждом большом магазине есть рыбный и мясной отделы, иногда отдел "Рыба и мясо", но никогда не бывает отдела "Мясо рыбы". Впрочем, формально Вы правы. Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: "Мясо рыбы (птицы)" - это отраслевой жаргонизм (как и "план по яйцу"), противоречащий бытовой практике языка и вызывающий в памяти поговорку "ни рыба, ни мясо". В узком бытовом смысле "мясо" без уточнений когда-то означало только говядину.

Comment: @Alex_ander В бытовом значении пельмени по определению делаются из мяса. Но даже те, кто не считает птицу мясом,  продолжают считать куриные пельмени пельменями, не замечая никаких противоречий. Многим такое бытовое мышление не по нутру — они стремятся к корректности в словах и мыслях вовсе не ради употребления "отраслевых жаргонизмов", закреплённых во всех толковых словарях, начиная как минимум с XVIII века (и ранее, наверное, я не проверял).

Comment: Не поняла Вас, Медведик. _В бытовом значении пельмени по определению делаются из мяса._ В детстве я жила на эстонском хуторе (недалеко от моря), где частенько пельмени были с гусем, с перепелкой, с угрем. Это как посмотреть — у кого какой быт, какой доступ к продуктам или какие религиозные ограничения. У Даля: пельмени — род вареников, начиненных мясом; иногда рыбой, капустой, грибами, редькой.

Comment: *В узком бытовом смысле "мясо" без уточнений когда-то означало только говядину.* Мне нравится такая трактовка. ;)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Я о том, что в словаре Даля много раз встречаются выражения "мясо рыбы", "мясо птицы" и т.п. И не только у Даля, но и намного раньше и всегда позже — во всех словарях. А Alex_ander считает, что это чисто "отраслевые жаргонизмы". Я даже не знаю, как по-другому назвать мясо криля, например. Неужели в салат можно добавить просто "криль", а не "мясо криля"? А как Вы скажете?

Comment: Простите, что не по теме, но хочется поделиться тем, что увидел (как "грамотно" сейчас пишут (см. заголовок)): https://news.sportbox.ru/Vidy_sporta/light_attletics/spbnews_NI1371956_Bolt_zajavil_chto_mog_by_pokazat_boleje_luchshij_mirovoj_rekord_pri_sovremennoj_obuvi.

Answer (score 2):

При имеющемся порядке слов это словосочетание воспринимается как некое "*мясо филе*" ("филе" в родительном падеже - мясо принадлежит филе, но в нём будто есть что-то ещё), относящееся к индейке. Возможно, составитель этого понятия рассматривал "филе индейки" как разновидность мяса, используемого для этого конкретного вида пельменей. Но он не позаботился об однозначности такого прочтения (для достижения желаемого можно было заключить "филе индейки" в кавычки, тем самым поставив слово "филе" в именительный падеж). Если не исключать из составленного понятия слово "мясо" (что предпочтительно), можно было бы изменить порядок слов: "*филе мяса индейки*" - это условно приемлемо, поскольку можно представить себе "мясо индейки", из которого вырезают "филе" и делают фарш. Соответственно, если составитель склонен к формализму (в его отрасли принят жаргон "мясо птицы/рыбы"), допустимы такие варианты:

- из филе мяса индейки;
- из мяса "филе индейки";

но лучше и проще было бы "**из филе индейки**" или (для однозначности понимания) "**с фаршем из филе индейки**".

Comment: Извините, _Alex_ander_, Вы не ошиблись? _...заключить "филе индейки" в кавычки, тем самым поставив два слова в именительный падеж..._ Ведь в этом сочетании "индейки" — это _всегда_ Р. п.

Comment: Здесь _мясо_ склоняется, а его условное название как продукта (для того и кавычки) - нет (ср. _из универмага "Детский мир"_).

Comment: Это понятно, конечно. Но тогда, _мне кажется_, лучше написать не "два слова", а "словосочетание".

Comment: Спасибо, исправил на _слово "филе"_.

Comment: Безупречно! Теперь без закавык.